# Exporting a universal animated format on Adobe Director?

Tags: flash, adobe-director

How can I export a director file that supports interactivity from Adobe Director for it to be played in Windows and Mac with the same file format? I can only think of .swf format which Director doesn't seem to offer....

The export options in director are as follows:

Formats:

```
.BMP
.AVI
.MOV
```

Publishing Settings:

```
.EXE
.APP
.DCR
.HTM
```

Answer (score 0):

A single dcr file could be played on both platforms.  But only if the user has Shockwave installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The aim was to consider all possibilities; user with no Shockwave installed. As a result; there isn't a way. The only option is to export it in 2 formats; .exe and .app (for those who might come across the same issue.)